# Theorem Numbering problem - Lettered subsections

Tags: errors, numbering, theorems, sections-paragraphs, amsart

I am trying to write theorems that will number based on section and subsection.

I know this is the default when you enter, for example:

```
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[subsection]
```

but when I do this, it only shows the subsection, not the section.  I think this may be because I have renamed my subsections to be lettered instead of numbered with the command:

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}}
```

My sections are numbered (1, 2, 3, etc.) and my subsections are lettered (A, B, C, etc.) When I use the `\newtheorem` command I get:

**Definition A.1** instead of **Definition 1.A.1**

Any idea why it is dropping the section number and how to fix?  (I am using the amsart document class)

Comment: It would be really helpful to have a compilable document, not just fragments. Are you really using `amsart`?

Comment: maybe you should be using `\numberwithin{section}{chapter}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what is requested?

[image]

The redefinition of `\thesubsection` as `{\Alph{subsection}}` strips the section information of course from `\thesubsection`.

`\thedefn` is using `\thesubsection.\arabic{defn}` due to its definition, so `\thesection` is missing then.

```
\documentclass{amsart}



\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[subsection]


\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}}

\renewcommand{\thedefn}{\thesection.\thesubsection.\arabic{defn}}

\begin{document}


\section{Foo}

\subsection{Foo subsection}

\begin{defn}
Foo 
\end{defn}



\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for.  Thank you! Much appreciated.